# Flex Toast style windows

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, mxml

How can i create toast style windows in Flex MXML application like following?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/creating_toast-style_windows.html

I want to use this component in flex MXML where as this component is based on Action Script.

Was anyone able to recreate or use it in MXML project?

Comment: Purpose of toast style windows is to display information at some time during the application lifetime. I don't see why you want to create them with MXML (which means at compile time)

Comment: i want to use that action script but i am building using mxml... and in that i need to show popup's at random moments with some data. So i wanna use this. I am trying to work through code to achieve that. I got popup's to work but when i display them too quickly they appear on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reused some of the files and made it work in Flex Builder 3. :)